# Codeigniter form validation will not run

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

It seems that there are may questions about form and form validation.

I've been having a problem getting my form validation to work. I created a sign up form that ask the user for various information. Then I created a form that will allow the user to edit his information. The form validation works perfectly on the sign up form, but I can't get it run the validation on the other form.

My view

```
<h1>Edit user</h1>

<div id="body">
        <p>Edit user information.</p>

    <?php 



    echo form_open('user_admin/user_update');

    echo validation_errors();

    echo form_hidden('id', $results->id);

    echo "<p><lable>Email:</lable>";
    echo form_input('email', $results->email);
    echo "</p>";


    echo "<p><lable>Name:</lable>";
    echo form_input('name', $results->name);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>Last name:</lable>";
    echo form_input('lastname', $results->lastname);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>Home address:</lable>";
    echo form_textarea('homeaddress', $results->homeaddress);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>Postal address:</lable>";
    echo form_textarea('posteladdress', $results->posteladdress);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>Mobile number:</lable>";
    echo form_input('mobile', $results->mobile);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>Home telephone:</lable>";
    echo form_input('hometel', $results->hometel);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><lable>ID number:</lable>";
    echo form_input('idnum', $results->idnum);
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('edit_submit', 'Update');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();

    ?>
```

My controller

```
 public function user_update()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('model_users');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('homeaddress', 'Home address', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('posteladdress', 'Postel address', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile number', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hometel', 'Home telphone', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('idnum', 'ID Number', 'required');


    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'This email address has already been registered. Please try again.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()==true)
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->model_users->update_info();
        echo "The users details have been updated successfully";
        redirect ('user_admin/user_main');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The users details were not updated. Please contact the admistrator!";


    }


}
```

With the controller in its current configuration I can get the database to update by changing the if statement to FALSE. So I now that the post information is passed to the database and updated.

Please could somebody look at my code a tell me what I've done wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: When you are edit mode it is not working? Why don't you use javascript for client side validation?

Comment: are you able to go to else on update button click ?

Comment: Yes it will run to the else statement and print the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try taking this line out of the code and then re try.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'This email address has already been registered. Please try again.');
```

I think this line is supposed to go into your own validation function. If it does work, then just read up on custom form validation functions on the codeigniter site.

If you are using HMVC, then that can cause some issues with custom functions in validation, but there quite easy ways around it, but you would have to Google for the exact answer.

Comment: Even if I remove the set_message from the code it still doesn't form validation still doesn't run.

Comment: Have you tried putting <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> into your else statement to see what it is that is causing the error?

Comment: I did what you suggested and placed the `echo validation_errors();`. into the else statement and it returns the error in the form. I would however like the form page to reload and then present the errors above the form when the page reloads. I got it to work this way in my sign up page.

Comment: If your form validates, then just redirect to another page (Confirmation page) within your if statement. If it does not, then just reload the same view and repopulate the form values with set_value("Field_name"). Use the echo validation_errors() above your form. If there are no errors, or if this is the first time the form was loaded, the validation_errors() will contain no text, so nothing will be printed.